# call all functions that have prefix

Tags: php, php-5.3

Is it possible in PHP to call all functions that have a certain prefix ?

for example i have 70 functions 
most start with

> *func1*.... *func2* ....

i want to call all functions that start with `_func1`
is there any PHP function for that ? something like call_user_func but instead of a callback name to pass it something like `'_func1*'`

i know i can do it with 'get_defined_functions' but wonder if there's already such a function.

Comment: What in god's name for, if I may ask?

Comment: @deceze well it could be used for many things. for example set of calls for some object that is dynamically generated ? plugins and plugin management ? ... etc ...

Comment: I find it pretty nonsensical to simply call a bunch of unknown functions just by name. I'd say that there's always a better design pattern to be followed whenever you feel you need to do this.

Comment: @deceze better design patterns does not give better performance in most cases, for my case this solution is the fastest and the one that the servers could handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$names=get_defined_functions();
foreach($names["user"] as $f)
{
  if(substr($f,0,6)=="_func1")
   {
       // now call $f
      //  call_user_func($f);
   }

}
```

Comment: actually my question was is there any OTHER way to do it instead of this :) if i didnt find any this will be the only correct one :)

Comment: There isn't any built-in functionality in PHP to do this, any other method will also be something that's user defined. That way there can be other ways too, for example store all your function names in an array and then call the ones you like etc. No built-in such functionality exists as far as I know

Comment: An option for filtering the array of function names is to use [`preg_grep()`](http://php.net/preg_grep). Combined with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map) and [`call_user_func()`](http://php.net/call_user_func), it could almost be a one-liner.

Comment: just wanted to be sure that there's not such function. thanks

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using methods from class, you can also use following :

for ex :

```
class myclass {
    // constructor
    function myclass()
    {
        return(true);
    }

    // method 1
    function myfunc1()
    {
        return(true);
    }

    // method 2
    function myfunc2()
    {
        return(true);
    }
}

$class_methods = get_class_methods('myclass');
// or
$class_methods = get_class_methods(new myclass());

foreach ($class_methods as $method_name) {
    echo "$method_name\n";
}
```

you can use sub string method in loop to get it working as per your need